# Is it true that $\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}x^iy^j \leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}x^ix^j\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}y^iy^j\right)}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, inequality

If $A$ is a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix is it true that $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}x^iy^j \leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}x^ix^j\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^{i,j}y^iy^j\right)},$$

where $x,y \in \mathbb{R^d}$?

I thought Holder's inequality could be applied but I don't think it works for signed measure spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive definition, for any $t>0$ we have
$$
A(x+ty)\cdot(x+ty)\geq0.
$$
That is
$$
Ax\cdot x+2tAx\cdot y+t^2Ay\cdot y\geq0,\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb R.
$$
So the discriminant of above is always non-positive and hence
$$
(Ax\cdot y)^2-(Ax\cdot x)\cdot(Ay\cdot y)\leq0.
$$
That is
$$
Ax\cdot y\leq\sqrt{Ax\cdot x}\cdot\sqrt{Ay\cdot y},
$$
as desired.

Comment: This is great! Thanks.